# Issues with keeping a div to the far right of browser window, whilst browsers dimensions are changing, after an animation effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a parent div that contains two other side-by-side divs. On click these divs move from one side to the other side of the browser window (click on left div, it moves far left, click right div and it moves to the far right of the browser) - I must say that up to here everything works just as I wish.

The problem arises when I try to manually re-size my browser by grabbing the bottom right and scaling it to a new dimension. When I do this the div stays in the exact same place (what was the far right of the original browser dimension) and so 'falls' out of view, it is crucial for me to have this div keep to the far right as the browser window is changing dimension.

I know that if say the div's css property is set to right:0 it should stay to the far right but for some reason the javascript animation effect does not seem to account or overrides this and keeps it in the original browser far right instead of following the new dimension.

Here is my current code in basic form to show you how I have it so far:

HTML:

```
<span id='one'>&nbsp;    
    <span id='two'>&nbsp;</span>
    <span id='three'>&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#one {
    height:100px;
    width:210px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
#two {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
#three {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:green;
    float:right;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#two').click(function(){
        window_width = $(document).width();
        element_width = $('#one').width();
        edge = window_width - element_width;
        $('#one').animate({right:edge, left:0}, 100).delay(0);
        console.log($('#one').css('left'));   
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#three').click(function(){
        window_width = $(document).width();
        element_width = $('#one').width();
        edge = window_width - element_width;
        $('#one').animate({left:edge, right:0}, 100).delay(0);
        console.log($('#one').css('left'));
    });
    console.log($('#one').css('left'));
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I have scoured SO for a good few days and struggled to find any resolving answer - Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your sizes in % in the css file, so they resize when you open the html from a monitor whit lower resolution. You can also check media querys out. They are pretty good for creating web pages, that look exactly the same on all kinds of resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you set a variable to hold the position of the divs, and then use the `.resize()` event handler from JQuery? For instance,

```
var isLeft = true;

$(window).resize(function() {
    if (!isLeft) {
        window_width = $(document).width();
        element_width = $('#one').width();
        edge = window_width - element_width;
        $('#one').animate({right:edge, left:0}, 100).delay(0);
        console.log($('#one').css('left'));
    }
});
```

And the same for the other div. You set the `isLeft` or `isRight` variable inside the click events.

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ2b6/)

```
var _pos;

$('#two').click(function () {
    window_width = $(window).width();
    element_width = $('#one').width();
    edge = window_width - element_width;
    $('#one').animate({
        right: edge,
        left: 0
    }, 100).delay(0);
    console.log($('#one').css('left'));
    _pos="left";
});

$('#three').click(function () {
    window_width = $(window).width();
    element_width = $('#one').width();
    edge = window_width - element_width;
    $('#one').animate({
        left: (edge > window_width)?window_width:edge,
        right: 0
    }, 100).delay(0);
    console.log($('#one').css('left'));
    _pos="right"
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   if (_pos=="left") $("#two").click();
   if (_pos=="right") $('#three').click();
});
```

---

The important part here is changing `$(document).width()` to `$(window).width()` as you want the div to adjust when the screen gets smaller and not just when it gets bigger.

Comment: This works exactly as I need it to, thank you. Is there a method of making #one keep to the right side of the browser with a bit more fluidity as when re-scaling the browser it does what I asked for in the above question but very jumpy/delayed and not as smooth as I'd ideally desire... as you can test in your demo when re-sizing your browser. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a listener to `window.onresize`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize